# Many to Many mapping objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

Am having two sets of arrays :

```
$scope.selectedEmployees = ["1001", "1002"];
$scope.selectedTasks = ["Task1", "Task2"];
```

I wanted to generate an array of objects by combining the employees and tasks like a many to many relationship.The length of $scope.selectedEmployees and $scope.selectedTasks may vary :

```
newArray=[
    {
        "empId": 1001,
        "task": "Task1"
    },
    {
        "empId": 1001,
        "task": "Task2"
    },
    {
        "empId": 1002,
        "task": "Task2"
    },
    {
        "empId": 1002,
        "task": "Task2"
    }
]
```

The method I tried:

```
 var newArray=[];
         for (var i = 0; i <$scope.selectedEmployees.length; i++) {
           for (var j = 0; j <$scope.selectedTasks .length; j++) {
    newArray.push({"empId":$scope.selectedEmployees[i],
                  "task":$scope.selectedIntervention[j]
                 })
                   }
                }
```

But i'm not able to get the required format.Any help will be grateful.

Comment: You forgot the `<` in your second for loop : `j<$scope...`

Comment: And it should be `selectedTasks` and not `selectedIntervention`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zuv8y9wk/

Also instead of selectedTasks, selectedIntervention was used

```
var $scope = {};
$scope.selectedEmployees = ["1001", "1002"];
$scope.selectedTasks = ["Task1", "Task2"];
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedEmployees.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.selectedTasks.length; j++) {
        newArray.push({
            "empId": $scope.selectedEmployees[i],
            "task": $scope.selectedTasks[j]
        })
    }
}
console.log(newArray)
```